# Excel Graph: colour datalabels as the same colour as line chart VBA

Tags: excel, vba, graph, colors

Is there a method to colour line chart datalabels automatically with the colour of a line chart? I have multiple series and it would be great to colour these automatically.

Comment: You should be able to make some progress by recording a macro while making the change to one series - use that as a starting point.

Comment: Have tried this. Doesn't seem that simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Dim cht As Chart, s As Series

Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart

For Each s In cht.SeriesCollection
    If s.HasDataLabels Then
        s.DataLabels.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = _
          s.Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB
    End If
Next s
```

Comment: Have been unable to get this to work. I'd like to select the final datalabel as this the only one displayed.

Comment: Currently this does not do anything to the chart

Comment: It's possible you'd need to look at the individual Points - http://www.java2s.com/Code/VBA-Excel-Access-Word/Excel/addthedatalabelsusingthefollowingcode.htm

Comment: Confused about the above link?

Comment: Sample code for you to try to adapt - shows how to access individual data points and their associated DataLabels

Comment: Thanks Tim. I'm interested in simply selecting only the last datapoint of each series.